# mv Operation not permitted in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, root, dnsmasq

**English Description**

I tried to move files in my folder using the terminal, using this code:

```
sudo mv dnsmasq / usr / sbin /
```

As a result I get the following error:

```
mv: rename dnsmasq to / usr / sbin / dnsmasq: Operation not permitted
```

even though I've followed this method:

Steps:

```
 Apple menu -> System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access -> +
```

Choose:

```
Applications -> Utilities -> folder -> Terminal -> open / grant terminal full disk access privileges. -> Relaunch terminal
```

Why does it still give an error message?

Answer (score 4):

In order to write to `/usr/sbin`, you need to disable the System Integrity Protection which is not recommended. If that's what you want you can disable it with the command `csrutil disable; reboot`, but its preferred to use `/usr/local/bin` and you won't have to disable SIP to write on it.

Comment: thank you for your answer , but its still not work for me